# IEnumerator.MoveNext() implementation?

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable

I am kind of new to c# i know a method defined in a interface has to be implemented

but in the below code i have not implemented MoveNext() method

```
static void Main()
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list.Add(1);
    list.Add(5);
    list.Add(9);

    List<int>.Enumerator e = list.GetEnumerator();
    Write(e);
}

static void Write(IEnumerator<int> e)
{
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        int value = e.Current;
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

I checked in metadata too, & it does not provide any implementation.

so why is the compiler not throwing any error?
where is the implementation of MoveNext() method &
how does it move to next value?

Is the code for MoveNext() method auto generated by compiler?
please help

Comment: You're calling `list.GetEnumerator()`. That returns an instance of `IEnumerator<int>`. Why would *you* have to implement it, when you have an instance of it? :)

Comment: If you were to have `class myClass : IEnumerator<int>` then it would force you to "implement" a move next.  But you have not declared that your class is of type `IEnumerator<int>`, you are consuming it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is, you did not implement `IEnumerator<int>`, you used `List<int>` which has implemented it and provided implementation for `MoveNext`.

Here is the [actual implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1209) and the code is:

```
public bool MoveNext() {

    List<T> localList = list;

    if (version == localList._version && ((uint)index < (uint)localList._size)) 
    {                                                     
        current = localList._items[index];                    
        index++;
        return true;
    }
    return MoveNextRare();
}
```